# Consulta sobre emular en Iphone 6s

Tags: android, ios

tengo un iphone 6s y estoy desarrollando una app en Android Studio. Queria saber si hay alguna manera de poder emular la aplicacion android en el iphone con un virtualBox o algo asi.

Gracias.

Comment: No, no es posible. Son plataformas completamente distintas.

Comment: Hola @Nicolas, bienvenido al sitio. Este tipo de preguntas son muy abiertas y no hay una respuesta correcta, por lo cual no está dentro de la temática del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por el momento no hay nada disponible sin embargo si hay en desarrollo.

Su nombre es **Droid4x** puedes suscribirte en su pagina para ser notificado cuando este disponible.

- [Video presentacion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBmdQxUCfYg&nohtml5=False)
- [Pagina del Proyecto](http://www.droid4x.com/#)

Comment: encontré un link muerto :C

Answer (score 1):

Nativamente no es posible, como lo comentan puedes tratar con iphoDroid, iAndroid etc. Aunque tu aplicación debe ser relativamente sencilla, ya que cuando usas cierto tipo de permisos, clases del SDK, no funciona tu aplicación correctamente y se cierra, además tienes que hacer jailbreak a tu iPhone, ¿estas seguro de esto?

Tanto para desarrollo o producción no usaría esta opción.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes ejecutar una aplicación Android en iOS<strike>, es como querer correr un ejecutable de Windows en Linux,</strike> simplemente es algo que es técnicamente muy complicado; Las aplicaciones Android necesitan la máquina virtual de Java [Dalvik](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik) que convierte el código intermedio en Java hacia la arquitectura nativa de cada dispositivo, se tendría que desarrollar una máquina virtual que corriera sobre iOS para que pudiese ser técnicamente factible, pero las restricciones de Apple no aceptarían dicha máquina (Siempre podrías intentar jailbrekear tu iphone pero jamas podría venderse en la tienda o ser "mainstream")

Si te refieres a que tienes una aplicación multiplataforma como con [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) o algo similar tendrías que generar el binario para iOS, es decir, generar el archivo .APP con la herramienta correspondiente, este APP es similar (bajo concepto) del APK de android, pero compilado bajo la arquitectura de iOS, porque a diferencia de Android se compila a código nativo.

Si te refieres a una web app puedes usar las [herramientas de desarrollo de chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) para cambiar el target a un dispositivo iOS para emular el browser y las resoluciones de cada dispositivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo como **dato** fuera de la pregunta, sí se pueden ejecutar ejecutables de Windows en Linux usando un software y no, no es complicado. (Solo como dato)

Comment: @x4mp73r listo, editada la respuesta XD

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta corta: **No es posible** nativamente.

Antes existían algunos proyectos para emular a través de apps en iPhone, pero parece que en este momento estan muertos

- iPhoDroid
- iAndroid
- BlueStacks

<sub>Nota: se necesita jailbreak en el iPhone</sub>